# MongoDB - Querying a field in a lower level of document

Tags: mongodb

Issue with fetching the data of a particular field within a document

The followoing is my collection structure

```
colleciton mail
   mailtype
   criteria 
      triggerinfor
            code   ---->  multiple codes are there.
            description
            status
```

Tried this but not working

```
db.getCollection('Mail').find(
{
    "MailType" :"Printed",
    "MailName" :"Welcomemail",
    "programType":"Maile",
    "criterias"  :
              {"triggerInformation":
                                  {"code"       :"MAIL007"},
                                  {"description":"1234 Welcome maile"}
              }
}
)
```

I have to retrieve the document with code MAIL007 only.. could some one help in getting a query for that

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it, depending on what you need:

**1- Matching an exact nested document:** this way, you are querying for documents that have a nested document that is **exactly** like the one in your search criteria.

```
db.getCollection('Mail').find(
{
    "MailType" :"Printed",
    "MailName" :"Welcomemail",
    "programType":"Maile",
    "criterias.triggerInformation": {
        "code": "MAIL007",
        "description": "1234 Welcome maile",
        "status": "some status"
    }
}
```

Notice that you need to explicitly inform a value to each of the nested document fields in your search criteria. If any field is missing the query will return nothing.

**2- Querying a field inside a nested document:** this way, you are querying for documents based on the value of one or more fields inside a nested document.

```
db.getCollection('Mail').find({
    "MailType":"Printed",
    "MailName":"Welcomemail",
    "programType":"Maile",
    $and: [
        {"criterias.triggerInformation.code": "MAIL007"},
        {"criterias.triggerInformation.description": "description":"1234 Welcome maile"}
    ]
})
```

In the code above you are querying for documents based on the values of the fields `code` and `description` inside the nested document `criterias.triggerInformation`.

You can find more info about querying nested documents at MongoDB's docs [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/)